# Possible to change view of related entries field?

Tags: control-panel, field

Is it possible to change the display of the related entries field, to include extra info (hoping to add thumbnail, because otherwise these entries are damn hard to identify!)

I don't *think* they are quite the same as a standard table view and therefore hookable by `defineAdditionalEntryTableAttributes`
Or can you override the normal view of the field type?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy task: you can create your own relations field and use that instead. 
Take a look at the default [Entries field](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-fields-entries.html) here is the php code for it [click](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/fields/Entries.php)

All you have to do is changing the template that should be rendered so you'll end up with something like

```
class MyCustomRelationField extends BaseRelationField
{
    // Static
    // =========================================================================
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function displayName(): string
    {
        return Craft::t('app', 'My awesome field');
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected static function elementType(): string
    {
        return Entry::class;
    }
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function defaultSelectionLabel(): string
    {
        return Craft::t('app', 'Add an entry');
    }

    /**
     * @var string Template to use for field rendering
     */
    protected $inputTemplate = 'path/to/your/custom/template';
}
```

the `$inputTemplate` is the template that gets rendered in the cp so you'll take the default one [here](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/templates/_includes/forms/elementSelect.html) as your base and change the parts you need

```
<div class="elements">
    {% for element in elements %}
        {% include "_elements/element" with {
            context: 'field',
            size: (viewMode == 'large' ? 'large' : 'small')
        } %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

to something you like. Because the default content in this include is generated [here](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/web/View.php#L1473). Take that as a reference what you have to change/include in your own template (or hook) together with your icon/thumbnail

Comment: Thanks so much for such a detailed answer Robin!
The `{% include "_elements/element" %}` lead me to a hook which I wasn't sure whether was overrideable, but I could easily add the necessary tweaks within my main template file, using `element.img...` and a bit of extra CSS